# Adding php 7.4 to wamp server 3.2.8

Tags: php, wamp, upgrade

I'm trying to add PHP 7.4 to WAMP server , I already added PHP 7.4 add-on, but its not showing in the list, i tried all solutions I found, but no use, I get this error in php_error.log

> #0 C:\wamp64\scripts\refresh.php(132): DateTime->__construct('\xD9\xA2\xD9\xA0\xD9\xA2\xD9\xA2-\xD9\xA0\xD9\xA4-\xD9...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\scripts\refresh.php on line 132

and in apache error log I get this error that does not make sense to me:

[image: wamp apache error]

any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you take the php folder off your path like the message suggested?

Comment: sorry for the very late reply, actually i did everything and the best action was reinstalling WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no answers, I just uninstalled WAMP and deleted WAMP folder from c: / drive completely after I backed up my sites and database, and reinstalled it, and this fixed the issue.

THANKS ANYWAY